# Is there a way to navigate to a function's definition in another file in VSCode or CLion for CPP?

Tags: c++, ide, visual-studio-code, clion

I am working in a project where I am on a specific file in a folder, the structure is like this:

```
└─project_folder/
    ├─ myFile.cpp
    └─ other_folder/
        ├─ headerFile.h
        └─ otherCppFile.cpp
```

Now I have a function **createBoundary()** in **myFile.cpp**, there are a lot of header files in **myFile.cpp** and I am not sure where the function is declared/defined. Is there a way to navigate to the function **createBoundary()**'s definition in VSCode or CLion? I have already tried doing that by going to options and clicking *"Go to definition"* but that didn't work and it only gave me a popup saying *"No definition was found"*.

PS. If the above said thing is not possible in both the mentioned IDEs and there's another IDE which facilitates that, do let me know please.

Comment: You can try to perform a search by going to the Solution Explorer tab, and clicking on Search Solution Explorer, maybe that will find it. Under options there is also Search External items.

Comment: @Tyler I am doing that, but the thing is, it also gives me all the locations where the function is used and apparently I am having 2k+ responses to my query which makes it tiresome to go through everything and find that one specific definition. I was hoping there's a better way to do that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Using Ctrl-Shift-F you can specify file types, presumably it is only in one header file.

Comment: I usually get "No definition found" in CLion if something with CMake isn't right...

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `Ctrl + P` or `Command + P` you can input the fileName and navigate to a file in VSCode (plus, it has some advanced features).

Now if you write `myFile` or `myFile.cpp` you can open the myFile.cpp and it also works for directories.
writing `components/index` in the input takes you to somewhere where the folder's name is components and opens a file named index which is located inside of the components folder

If you write `myFile:122` it takes you to the file myFile.cpp and line 122.
Now if you write `myFile.cpp@createBoundary` it opens the file myFile.cpp, finds whatever value or function or anything that has the name `createBoundary` and puts the cursor on it.

If the createBoundary is inside of another object or function, you can use `myfile.cpp#createBoundary`. So you don't have to navigate all the way down to the corresponding line of code.

By the way, when you've already opened the file, you don't need to write the fileName anymore, just `#createBoundary` or `@createBoundary` or `:122` is enough that time.